# Windows Azure URL Redirect

Tags: azure, http-redirect

My team has hosted an azure cloud service: Site is like `https://<test>.cloudapp.net` and it uses ADFS authentication which means it gets redirected to corp sts site for authentication

Our requirement is to use something like [http://test] or [https://test] which should redirect to `https://<test>.cloudapp.net`.

We also added a CNAME for [.cloudapp.net]  in DNS and this does not seem to work.

Comment: ".cloudapp.net" is not valid.  Do you mean something like "myapp.cloudapp.net"?  If that's the case, it should work.

Comment: I meant https://test.cloudapp.net . Sorry for the typo. It does not work as expected and redirection does not happen

Comment: I've done the CNAME redirect with at least one cloudapp.net url... any other details like error messages that could help us analyse the problem?

Comment: no error. with CName [https://test] it displays page ''HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found' Can you let us know if there is any configuration change required on azure cloud service or the web.config file of the application running on cloud service

Comment: And does http://test.cloudapp.net give you a 404 too?

Comment: No test.cloudap.net works absolutely fine

Comment: And you've entered the CNAME in the Azure Portal?

Comment: What have you got running on that cloud service that responds to http requests?

Comment: WE are running the cloud service and not azure website hence not sure where to enter the CName. Can you please elaborate on your last question about what you got running..??

Comment: A "cloud service" is just a place holder--you have to deploy something to that cloud service (from Visual Studio that's usually organized in a .cspkg file).  It's what is deployed that needs to be configured.  An Azure Web Site is configured through the Azure portal. The fact that you mentioned you're trying to access it from http://test.cloudapp.net suggested to me that you had deployed an Azure web site.